# (react-native-fcm) How to local notification for indivisual devices with device_token?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I'm trying to integrate local notifications from react-native-fcm into my application.
My app is sharing diaries app.
and every diary have "nice" button.

What i want to do is that user A press user B's "nice" button of userB's diary. then push notification was sent to only userB's device.
like "pressed nice button".

how to accomplish this?
I can get device_token with react-native-device-info.
I'm using rails api server on AWS.

thanks.